# I have both adobe Photoshop 6.0 and 7.0. How do i save multiple sets automatically, as say, JPG files?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

Thanks for looking but please do not answer with solutions to Photoshops that are newer than 7.0

I have both adobe Photoshop 6.0 and 7.0. How do I save multiple sets automatically, as say, JPG files? Even automatically saving individual layers would be better than nothing, as i could flatten each set.

I seem to be only able to find solutions for newer versions.

For example I have 30 layers. Each layer is its own image. I want to save each set has layers that represent a jpg file. name doesn't matter as long as there ends up with 30 jpg files.

I do not see Scripts in my versions of photoshop.

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to flatten anything. Just switch on the layers you want, and hide the layers you don't want, and do File > Save AS > choose jpeg.  JPEGs are flattened anyway.

I can't see any way of automating this even in newer versions of Photoshop, if your choice of layers to include in "sets" depends on human choice.  It might help if you were to arrange your "sets" in groups.  I think older versions of PS had groups, although I can't really remember.

Comment: I think groups were added around Photoshop 6 if I remember correctly

Comment: The question was how to save MULTIPLE SETS AUTOMATICALLY.  I know how to save a layer as a jpg, you simply save as when on the active layer. But try that method with 100 layers. my question is that I wanted to automate this.  But thanks anyway.

Comment: That's what I answered. Let me clarify. Photoshop has no "sets" functionality - only groups. If you arranged your sets into 30 groups instead, that may make the task easier. You could simply enable each group you need, hiding the others, and then export. I can't see a way of automating the task if the choice of which layers to include in the output jpeg depends on human input. Sorry if that wasn't clear.

Answer (score 0):

Easy way is recording a script to export the file as jpg(halt) ;
then keep your layer panel every layer hidden - 
each time un-hide a layer and run the script, save with file (Alhpabets ).

Comment: As I said, Photoshop 6 / 7  does not have scripts. So your answer does not apply unless there is some hidden wy to do scripts. But thanks anyway. I was hoping for a definitive answer of either:  1) HERE IS HOW in detail, or 2) it can not be done